# Add items from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

1) The first array:

```
array(

    [0] => array(
              [code] => code_1
              [value] => xxx
    [1] => array(
              [code] => code_2
              [value] => xxx     
    [2] => array(
              [code] => code_3
              [value] => xxx
```

2) The second array:

```
array(

    [0] => array(
              [settingcode] => code_1
              [value] => xxx
    [1] => array(
              [settingcode] => code_2
              [value] => xxx     
    [2] => array(
              [settingcode] => code_3
              [value] => xxx
    [3] => array(
              [settingcode] => code_4
              [value] => xxx     
    [4] => array(
              [settingcode] => code_5
              [value] => xxx
```

How can add two missing items (`code_4` and `code_5`) from array2 to array1?

Thank you!

**UPD.**

Sorry, I need to clarify the question a bit. I need the resulting array to look like:

```
array(

    [0] => array(
              [code] => code_1
              [value] => xxx
    [1] => array(
              [code] => code_2
              [value] => xxx     
    [2] => array(
              [code] => code_3
              [value] => xxx
    [3] => array(
              [code] => code_4
              [value] => xxx     
    [4] => array(
              [code] => code_5
              [value] => xxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add($from, $to)
{
 foreach($from as $key => $value)
 {
  if($to[$key] == "")
       $to[$key] = $value;
 }
 return $to;
}
```

array_merge would be the better way, however

Answer (score 7):

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the keys of the array to identify the value, then this will work

```
$resulting_array = $array2 + $array1;
```